# How to Merge a fixed path either to local pc or network adress with cell value as filenames

Tags: excel, vba, merge

i have been trying to figure out how to add VBA code that gives an output to a cell with combined info as  :  Fixed PAth example \folder1\folder2 + Filename from cell value.      I have manged to get a hyperlink to work but not when i want to refer to the harddrive or network path.

Part of Code i have / been using are :

```
Worksheets("Import").Activate
Dim lastLng As Long
lastLng = Worksheets("Import").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
 Range("A4:A" & lastLng).Formula = "=""\\folder1\folder2\folder3\Media\Pictures\"" & C4 & "".jpg"""
```

What happend here is that Excel show the path in the cell as i want except for the part where i want cell c4  to show : It is showing like this :

```
"\\folder1\folder2\folder3\Media\Pictures\" & C4 & ".jpg"
```

But i want it to show like this :

```
\\folder1\folder2\folder3\Media\Pictures\554682.jpg
```

( where the number are from a cell)

Updated*  Thanks to Siddhart, i managed now to make it show like i wanted.  "But another issue appear with another part of the code that will import miniature images into cells based on the path above. This code was working before when using url, but it seem like it doesnt manage to get the images when i use path from either my harddrive or network address."

**Updated again My bad and stupidity**, it is working it was only my brain that did not work :)    Again thanks for the help here.   It might be i will ask again later as im trying to build up this complex but a user friendly little tool for my collegues to save time when making assortment lists with fixed setup, products and pictures based on an exported file from our system :)

The code for importing pictures i have been using is this:

```
  Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()


    Dim theShape As shape
    Dim xRg As Range
    Dim xCol As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Set rng = Worksheets("Import").Range("A4:B1000")
    For Each cell In rng
        Filename = cell
        If InStr(UCase(Filename), "JPG") > 0 Then
            Worksheets("Import").Pictures.Insert(Filename).Select
            Set theShape = Selection.ShapeRange.Item(1)
            If theShape Is Nothing Then GoTo isnill
            xCol = cell.Column
            Set xRg = Cells(cell.Row, xCol)
            With theShape
                .LockAspectRatio = msoFalse
                .ScaleHeight 0.1, msoTrue
                .ScaleWidth 0.1, msoTrue
                '.Width = 50
                '.Height = 50
                .Top = xRg.Top + (xRg.Height - .Height) / 2
                .Left = xRg.Left + (xRg.Width - .Width) / 2
            End With
isnill:
            Set theShape = Nothing
            Range("e1").Select
        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

    Debug.Print "Done " & Now


End Sub
```

From what i understand on the code above the code gets the file path from A4 to B1000,  and i guess the issue are where it says filename = cell ?(my skill with VBA = almost to 0)
Also line under "Instr Ucase" part it says jpg - im not sure if this is needed as the whole filename in the path will determ if its jpg, png etc.

Comment: What are you trying to do with this part? `Range("A4:A" & lastLng).Formula` Are you trying to set the value of that range of cells to the `Fixed Path`? @4Amp

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code. The problem that you mentioned happens when the range (*Cells in Column A in your case*) is formatted as `Text`. Change the format to `General`

Comment: @ Siddhart    Thank you  i then managed to get showing up right :)   But i see now that i have a another problem with another code that will use this path to add pictures miniature pictures into cells as it seem like it doesnt manage to read the Path and get the images from the drive the same way as it did before when i used url.     I have updated Thread her with that part of the code also.